# How to create a layout containing a textview with buttons on either side

Tags: android, android-layout

How would one create a layout with a button on either side of a textview? This is what I've got so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/left_button"
        android:layout_width="72dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/center_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="textview" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right_button"
        android:layout_width="72dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem here is that the textview is centered. I want the textview to fill the complete space left. I tried setting its android:layout_width to fill_parent and removing the android:layout_centerHorizontal, but then it seems to overlap the buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step-1**

You need create first button in the left of the screen mention `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

**Step-2**

create second button in the right of the screen mention `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

**Step-3**

Now create TextView and mention the it in the right of first buttona and left of second button by mentioning

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_button"
```

**XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/left_button"
            android:layout_width="72dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="left" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/right_button"
            android:layout_width="72dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="right" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/center_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_button"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_button"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="textview" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This seemed to fix the problem. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you would be better served by a LinearLayout, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/left_button"
        android:layout_width="72dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/center_textview"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:text="textview" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right_button"
        android:layout_width="72dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="right" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This way the three views will all be in a single horizontal line and the TextView will take up any remaining space after the buttons are laid out (see the android:layout_weight property).

Comment: This was useful for better understanding the android:layout_weight property! Will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

These attributes may solve your problem

```
android:layout_toLeftOf
android:layout_toRightOf
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a LinearLayout with orientation="horizontal", as oppose to a RelativeLayout.

Or if you want to do RelativeLayout, you can use the attributes Chandra mentioned (i.e., align the textview relative to the buttons, instead of relative to the parent container).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but you could use for example. layout_toRightOf. An example that aligns the button to parent left and then lays the views to the right of the left one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/left_button"
    android:layout_width="72dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="left" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/center_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_button"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:text="textview" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/right_button"
    android:layout_width="72dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/center_textview"
    android:text="right" />

</RelativeLayout>
```